# Is it an SEO problem if I overuse a keyword in my page text when it is my domain name?

Tags: seo, domains, keywords, keyword-stuffing

I have a domain name which is also a keyword. like `clothes.deals`.
My page has 2000 words, and the domain keyword ("clothes.deals" with a dot) is found 14 times on my website text. I rank for my domain keyword ("clothes deals") in position #5 on Google.

1. Do too many domain name keywords on my page text can affect SEO negatively? (especially that my domain name is a targeted keyword so maybe Google will see this as Keyword stuffing)
2. Would it help if I changed some of the domain keywords from "clothes.deals" to "clothes-deals" or "clothes deals"? (Then Google might not treat these keywords as a phrase.)

Comment: It's common for a website to get impressions based on domain or branded queries. Not really sure what you are asking in your questions but you don't want to KW stuff the content of the page.

Comment: I have edited the questions to make them more clear. I just ask if this can be picked up by Google as keyword stuffing.

Comment: If you are ranking #5 for something competitive, I would say it seems to be working for you as is.   Why rock the boat?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have "clothes.deals" in the body of your text 14 times? It would make more sense for it to be simply "clothes deals".

1. Even so, if "clothes.deals" in considered one word, out of 2000 total words that's only a 0.7% KW density. I doubt that is high enough to affect your performance, especially since you say you are already ranking "#5".
2. > Would it help if I changed some of the domain keywords from "clothes.deals" to "clothes-deals" or "clothes deals"

What does this mean?

- If you are saying you want to change your *domain name* to something
  else, I would recommend against it. You can look into those
  alternatives to see if they have a higher domain authority or more
  backlinks.
- If within the content of your page you have "clothes.deals" all over 
  it and you are wanting to change it to something else, yes, please 
  change it to "clothes deals" without any periods of hyphens.

Overall, you want the content of your page to contain real words and real text that humans would read and understand. That's one of the most important items to search engines nowadays.